# How to transform pgf commands in a pgfkeys ".code" macro

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfkeys

I have a pgf shape, and I want the possibility of building it with certain keys which add optional parts to the shape. These keys are drawing the optional parts using the `.code` pgfkeys parameter. The problem is that when I draw my shape in different places on the page, or with a `scale` command, these optional parts do not move properly.

**How can I get the optional parts to move and scale with the rest of the shape?**

Here is my current code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\makeatletter
\pgfkeys{/tikz/east/.code={
    \color{#1}
    \pgfpathcircle{\pgfpoint{1cm}{0cm}}{0.1cm}
    \pgfusepath{fill}}
}
\pgfkeys{/tikz/east/.default=black}
\pgfdeclareshape{my circle}{
    \savedanchor\centerpoint{
        \pgf@x=0pt
        \pgf@y=0pt
    }
    \anchor{center}{\centerpoint}
    \foregroundpath{
        \pgfpathcircle{\pgfpoint{0cm}{0cm}}{1cm}
        \pgfusepath{stroke}
    }
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [my circle, scale=1, east=blue] at (0cm,1cm) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\]
\end{document}
```

Here I am passing the parameter "east=blue", which is supposed to draw a little blue blob on the east side of my circle. I'm drawing the node at (0cm,1cm), but the little blue blob is drawn as if the circle was centred at (0cm,0cm). Here is the output:

[image]

The desired output would be for the little blob to be drawn at the easternmost point of the circle shape, regardless of the coordinates the shape is drawn at, and use of the `scale` and `rotate` commands.

Comment: Another way to do it, which would solve the problem, would be to write code within the `backgroundpath` macro to detect which keys have been passed, and with what arguments. I have tried for hours to do that without success - maybe someone else knows how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to reinvent the wheel, err circle, look it up in the tikz code. ;-) However, I do not think it is necessary here. Here is a proposal that I think does what you want.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\tikzset{my circle/.style={circle,draw,minimum size=2cm,alias=mycirc},
my east/.style={append after command={
             \pgfextra{\fill[#1] (\tikzlastnode.east) circle (1mm);}}}}
\begin{document}
\foreach \X in {0.5,0.55,...,2} % animation just for fun
{\begin{tikzpicture}
\path[use as bounding box] (-2,-1) rectangle (2,3); % just for the animation
\node [my circle, scale=\X,my east=blue] at (0cm,1cm) {};
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**
It really didn't work with `scale`. This solution does however:

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\makeatletter
\def\blob@east{0}
\tikzset{
    blob east/.code={\def\blob@east{1}\def\blob@east@color{#1}},
    blob east/.default=black,
}
\pgfdeclareshape{my circle}{
    \savedanchor\centerpoint{
        \pgf@x=0pt
        \pgf@y=0pt
    }
    \anchor{center}{\centerpoint}
    \foregroundpath{
        \pgfpathcircle{\pgfpoint{0cm}{0cm}}{1cm}
        \pgfusepath{stroke}
        \ifnum\blob@east=1
            \pgfsetcolor{\blob@east@color}
            \pgfpathcircle{\pgfpoint{1cm}{0cm}}{1mm}
            \pgfusepath{fill}
        \fi
    }
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\foreach \Scale in {1,2,3,4}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \path (-5,-4) rectangle (15,6);
        \node [my circle, scale=\Scale, blob east=blue] at (0,1) {};
        \node [my circle, scale=\Scale] at (10,1) {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{document}
```

### [image]

**Old answer**
I'm not sure how to do this with the low level `\pgf...` commands, but if you only want to draw a dot relative to the node you can do it with some higher level commands quite easily.

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\makeatletter
%\pgfkeys{/tikz/east/.code={
%    \color{#1}
%    \pgfpathcircle{\pgfpoint{1cm}{0cm}}{0.1cm}
%    \pgfusepath{fill}}
%}
\tikzset{
    east/.style={
        append after command={
            \pgfextra{
                \fill[shift={(\tikzlastnode)},#1] (1cm,0) circle (0.1cm);
            }
        },
    },
}
\pgfkeys{/tikz/east/.default=black}
\pgfdeclareshape{my circle}{
    \savedanchor\centerpoint{
        \pgf@x=0pt
        \pgf@y=0pt
    }
    \anchor{center}{\centerpoint}
    \foregroundpath{
        \pgfpathcircle{\pgfpoint{0cm}{0cm}}{1cm}
        \pgfusepath{stroke}
    }
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [my circle, scale=1, east=blue] at (0cm,1cm) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this interesting idea! I don't think this would work with the `scale` command though.

Comment: @JamieVicary You were right about the `scale` key. The new solution works.